# Using PIVOT and JOIN together

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Consider This Query:

```
SELECT [Order Details].OrderID,
   c.CategoryName,
   COUNT(c.CategoryID)
FROM   [Order Details]
   INNER JOIN Products p
        ON  p.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
   INNER JOIN Categories c
        ON  c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
GROUP BY
   [Order Details].OrderID,
   c.CategoryName
ORDER BY
   [Order Details].OrderID
```

this query returns this such result (Usnig Northwind Database):

[image]

I want to use Pivot with Join to get such this result:

```
OrderID    Condiments    Produce    Seafood    Condiments    Grains/Cereals    ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10250           1            1           1          0              0             ...
10251           1            0           0          0              2             ...
...
```

How I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT [Order Details].OrderID,
                c.CategoryName,
                c.CategoryID
         FROM   [Order Details]
                INNER JOIN Products p
                  ON p.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
                INNER JOIN Categories c
                  ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID)
SELECT *
FROM   T PIVOT ( COUNT (CategoryID) FOR CategoryName IN ( 
       [Beverages],
       [Condiments],
       [Confections], 
       [Dairy Products], 
       [Grains/Cereals],
       [Meat/Poultry],
       [Produce],
       [Seafood]) ) AS pvt
ORDER  BY OrderID
```